# How do we can make a image to take the whole space available in the floating action button in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a image in floating action button which I have done easily but the problem I am facing is that I don't know how to make this image to take the whole space available in the floating action button ... I tried my best researched in the internet but did not not fount anything ...any help is appreciated thanks in advance

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
floatingActionButton: Container(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.24,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.24,
child: FloatingActionButton(
//backgroundColor:Colors.lightGreen,
child: Image.asset("assets/home_unselected.png"),
onPressed: () {}),
),
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of `CircleAvatar` widget and pass the desired image as `backgroundImage` alongwith giving a custom `radius` to it, as below:

```
child: FloatingActionButton(
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 50,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/placeholder.png",
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {}),
```

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: thank you  so much sir but sir the image i am using is still not covering the whole button it is covering on this place holder image i tried with this one also ......any other suggestion sir

Comment: Can you add the image in your original question ?

Comment: sorry sir i cant share the image because of the project confidentiality...hope you understand the problem I am facing sir is that i am able to see the background of the floating action button  if i change it to different color for example white ...like it is showing on your image also but in mine it is a bit bigger .....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried warping the "Image" widget with "Expanded" widget?

Not sure about this though.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to put your widget immediately as the child for the floatingActionButton attribute:

```
      floatingActionButton: Image.asset("assets/icons/send_icon.png"),
```

By this way, you won't have unwanted padding.

You can find more info in the doc by double-clicking the attribute:

```
  /// A button displayed floating above [body], in the bottom right corner.
  ///
  /// Typically a [FloatingActionButton].
  final Widget? floatingActionButton;
```